# Urgent help for cheesecake

Tags: cheesecake

I just baked a chocolate chip cheesecake in the oven for 65 minutes and forgot to put a water bath in there! what do I do to make sure that it's done okay? I don't have a thermometer. Did I ruin the whole thing?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Can you use the tooth pick test ?, it should be dry-ish.

or the jiggly test ? it should not be too jiggly.

https://www.bhg.com/recipes/how-to/bake/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-baked-cheesecake-is-done

(I have no experience with cheesecakes)

Answer (score 6):

If the recipe called for 65 minutes with a water bath and you baked it for 65 minutes without one, it will certainly be done and almost certainly taste good.

The texture might be different than the recipe intended because you've effectively let it get a bit hotter, and the surface might have cracks (which is only an issue if you care a lot what it looks like). I'd be very surprised if it's ruined!